# Multiple selects in Active Admin, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Okay, I have product with set of avaiable sizes (from 36 to 45). How can I set multiple sizes in Active Admin so they can be showed in my front-end? Like when I create a new product, I set a title, a description, a price and then a set of avaiable sizes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's depend on your Database and your Models.

Here are some possibilities:

A. You can use a String field to store and edit the Sizes. In your frontend you can access the sizes array via the method, in the backend and your database you use the sizes_string. In the backend you can enter data like `36, 45`. Benefit you can build a parser that can convert `36-45` to `36, 37, ...`

```
class Model < AR:Base
  # has a field sizes_string
  def sizes
    sizes_string.split(",")
  end
end
```

B. depend on what kind of database you use, you maybe can store the data as a array in the DB. Then you still need the string hack for the backend. You can do the following:

```
class Model < AR:Base
  # has a field sizes, which is an array
  def sizes_string
    sizes.join(", ")
  end

  def sizes_string= value
    self.sizes = value.split(", ")
  end
end
```

C. You can create a Size model and use a has_many relation. ActiveAdmin can provide a UI for has_many.

Comment: I think I'm comfortable with creating a Size model. Can you describe workflow? Should I create a migration for this model? In size model should I describe relations like belongs_to :products and in product model has_many :sizes, right? Where should I specify an array where I store avaiable sizes? Thank you